# Handling multi-index columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
CAR  MAKER  MODEL    0       1
CYL                4  6    4  6

     HONDA  CIVIC  5  0    0   0
     TOYOTA HLAND  0  0    10  15
     HONDA  PILOT  0  0    10   2
     TOYOTA COROLLA 0 5    5    4
```

The `df` is an `MultiIndex` with `CAR` having `0` and `1` and for each `CAR` there are  `4` and `6` as possibilities for `CYL`
I want to arrange the `df` such that it results in the following output:

```
MAKER   MODEL   0_4  0_6  1_4 1_6
HONDA   CIVIC   5     0    0   0
TOYOTA  HLAND   0     0    10  15
HONDA   PILOT   0     0    10   2
TOYOTA  COROLLA 0     5     5   4
```

I have tried to `reset_index(col_level=2)` but no success so far.
Any ideas on which method I can use to reorganize the `df`?
Its essentially the reverse of the `https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame`
`df.columns` is:

```
MultiIndex([(  'MAKER', ''),
            ('MODEL', ''),
            (                0,  4),
            (                0,  6),
            (                1,  4),
            (                1,  6)],
           names=['CAR', 'CYL'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post `df.to_dict` ? It's not very clear if `MAKER  MODEL` are two columns or index.

Comment: @Psidom they are two columns. the actual DF is quite large to do ````df.to_dict```` but here is ````df.columns````

Comment: No need to post all rows. Posting `df.head(6).to_dict()` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}" if x[1] else f"{x[0]}")
print(df)

# Output
    MAKER    MODEL  0_4  0_6  1_4  1_6
0   HONDA    CIVIC    5    0    0    0
1  TOYOTA    HLAND    0    0   10   15
2   HONDA    PILOT    0    0   10    2
3  TOYOTA  COROLLA    0    5    5    4
```

Comment: OMG :) thats so elegant!!! Thanks!